# Using OUTPUT to return both the newly Inserted Id and the original Id from a table during an INSERT

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got a load of tables where I need to clone subsets of data from. I've done this recursively using a number of loops which does complete the job, but is very slow.

The problem is that the hierarchy on the tables is structured using `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` columns which means I have to keep mapping old `Id`'s to new `Id`'s etc.

I want to be able to bulk clone each stage and do this mapping using the `OUTPUT` statement but I can't achieve this because I don't have access to the `FROM` table in the `OUTPUT` statement. The below example shows what I want to achieve but doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE #NewIds (IdNew INT, IdOld INT)

INSERT INTO IdTest
OUTPUT inserted.Id, i.Id
INTO #NewIds
SELECT id
FROM IdTest i
WHERE id IN (SELECT Id FROM #IdTestsToClone)
```

Can anyone explain to me how to get this working?